# Sequence function on existing data

Tags: sequence

[picture of example dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdWbI.png)
I am looking for a function to change the values from 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 etc. to every 5 in R. I have a big dataset similar to column A and B and would like to change it to columns H and I (like shown in the attached picture).

I'd like to change every cm til every 5 cm so that species that covers 5cm or shorter than 5 cm are registered as a point (similar to equ_palu). Moreover, the specie bet_nana covers 0-10 cm and is therefore registered as 5 and 10 in column H and I.

Comment: so `[0,5]->5, [6,10]->10` and so on?

Comment: Yes, but also including the column with the species names.

Comment: what you mean? once you have transformed the first column, you can get the name using `names[cm.array['cm']]` or whatever you have saved those data

Comment: Ok, I'll try that thanks. How would I write the first part [0,5]->5, etc?

Comment: probably just `round(your.data[cm]/5)*5` and you should be good to go